# Remove ability to access certain admin menus

Tags: admin, user-roles, admin-menu

I am trying to remove some of the admin features for a user with the role of contributor. What i mean by remove some of the admin features is disable them from seeing certain admin menu items, such as comments, tools, media ect. I have managed to remove the items I want from the admin menu, using this code:

```
function remove_menus(){

$author = wp_get_current_user();
if(isset($author->roles[0])){ 
    $current_role = $author->roles[0];
}else{
    $current_role = 'no_role';
}

if($current_role == 'contributor'){  
  remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
  remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
  remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
  remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );               //Comments

}

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

It works a treat. The problem I am facing is that I can just manually add the query string to the url, eg /wp-admin/edit.php and that will take me to the post edit screen. Does anyone know a way to restrict these pages from being accessed altogether, as well as hiding them from the admin menu?

Comment: Exactly what do you want this user to be able to do? It sounds more like you need a custom role rather than trying to hack the contributor role the way you are.

Comment: I want the user to be able to edit their profile and manage their own posts of a custom post type. I don't really think I need a custom role, as the contributor one is doing what I need just fine. I just need a way of stopping certain pages from being viewed in the admin area. If i create a custom role and give them the ability to manage their own posts, surely the same problem would occur?

Comment: How can i disable a particular user type access to Woocommerce settings?

Comment: @MOSD do not post a question as the solution to another question. I know you don't have the reputation to leave comments on other peoples questions but that is no excuse, and you'll get flagged as a spammer by the anti-spam system if you continue

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out in the end and this is the code I used:

```
function restrict_menus() {
    $author = wp_get_current_user();

    if( isset( $author->roles[0] ) ) { 
        $current_role = $author->roles[0];
    } else {
        $current_role = 'no_role';
    }

    if( 'contributor' == $current_role ) {  
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        $base   = $screen->id;


        if( 'edit-post' == $base || 'upload' == $base || 'tools' == $base || 'edit-comments' == $base ) {
            wp_die( 'Cheatin’ uh?' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'restrict_menus' );
```

Comment: this was really helpful, thanks for following up with your own solution

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has already been answered, and is old. I did, however, want to provide an alternate solution. This is how I did it in a plugin I wrote a while back (I've modified my code to use your pages).

Because you're wanting to restrict the contributor role, you can use [role capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). Contributors cannot publish posts, so you could do the following.

**Part 1: Remove Items from the Admin menu**

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'tcd_remove_admin_menus' );
function tcd_remove_admin_menus() {

    // don't do anything if the user can publish posts
    if ( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // remove these items from the admin menu
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );          // Posts
    remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );        // Media
    remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );         // Tools
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); // Comments

}
```

As you said though, it doesn't restrict the user from still just entering in the direct page url. Here's how I wrote my page restriction:

**Part 2: Restrict Access to Admin Pages**

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'tcd_restrict_admin_pages' );
function tcd_restrict_admin_pages() {

    // don't do anything if the user can publish posts
    if ( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // retrieve the current page's ID
    $current_screen_id = get_current_screen()->id;

    // determine which screens are off limits
    $restricted_screens = array(
        'edit',
        'upload',
        'tools',
        'edit-comments',
    );

    // Restrict page access
    foreach ( $restricted_screens as $restricted_screen ) {

        // compare current screen id against each restricted screen
        if ( $current_screen_id === $restricted_screen ) {
            wp_die( __( 'You are not allowed to access this page.', 'tcd' ) );
        }

    }

}
```

For me, using role capabilities and an array made it a little easier to work with. Anyway, I hope this method is helpful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use (and recommend) the [Members plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/).  The UI is very easy to use, and you have the added benefit of storing your role/permission logic in the database (rather than the code) which makes "on-the-fly" changes easy to do.

This plugin allows you to even create a custom role (maybe you want to invent one called "Photo Editor" or "Comment Approver" etc) and limit which menus they may see & access.  I think this will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could [create a custom role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) as suggested by s_da_hum or remove capabilities from the contributor role by adding this code to your child themes functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpsites_remove_contributor_capabilities' );

function wpsites_remove_contributor_capabilities() {

$contributor = get_role( 'contributor' );

$caps = array(
    'edit_posts',
    'delete_posts',
);

foreach ( $caps as $cap ) {

    $contributor->remove_cap( $cap );
    }
}
```

Source https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role