# Hide WordPress Plugin Deactivation Links

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks

How to hide deactivation link from all WordPress plugin page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a filter called [`plugin_action_links`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_action_links/) that lets you do this.

```
function wpse253902_disable_plugin_deactivation ($actions, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context) {
  if (array_key_exists ('deactivate', $actions)) unset( $actions['deactivate'] ); 
  return $actions;
  }
```

There is even a filter [`plugin_action_links_{plugin_name}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_action_links_plugin_file/) that lets you control the links on individual plugins. If you dive into it, you will find out that you can also use this to define your own links.

Answer (score 2):

You could restrict the plugin menu to only certain user access levels like admin. You will still want the link to be available without making a code change in the backend. 
This article should help you if you want to go this route.
[Remove ability to access certain admin menus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142517/remove-ability-to-access-certain-admin-menus)

Answer (score 0):

First: Why would you want that?

If you run your wordpress install as a multisite/network, you can install plugins on the "root", and activate for network. I believe that will make the plugin deactivation inaccessible on any subsite you set up. I haven't had that need myself, but I suppose it is possible. Another way to do it is to control the users admin rights, like only giving your users the role of author.