# Transform internationalized plugin into internationalized mu-plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, localization

I developed a custom plugin with the following structure in my folders:

```
wp-content
--- plugins
------ my-plugin
--------- languages
------------ po and mo files
--------- my-plugin.php
```

I internationalized it, and the translations all worked successfully. Now, I need that plugin to be a must-use plugin, by using the following structure:

```
wp-content
--- mu-plugins
------ my-plugin
--------- languages
------------ po and mo files
------ my-plugin.php
```

(The main plugin file has to be placed directly into the mu-plugins directory to be executed, from what I learned).

I now corrected all the paths in my main plugin file, due to the slight change of the location of the main plugin file (not inside the `my-plugin` folder anymore, but inside the `wp-content/mu-plugins` folder, as explained above), and all my functionalities are working, except from the programmed internationalization. I don't get what I'm still missing. Below's what I did:

Code in main plugin file when it was still a normal plugin, with localizations working:

```
// Callback loading the textdomain 'my-plugin', defined as such in header of main plugin file
public function my_plugin_load_plugin_textdomain() {
      load_plugin_textdomain(
        'my-plugin',
        false,
        basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'//languages/'
      );
}

// Hook of it
add_action(
        'plugins_loaded',
        array( $this, 'my_plugin_load_plugin_textdomain' )
      );
```

Here everything worked without any problem (I coded my whole main plugin file inside a class, that's why you have `array( $this, callback )` above). When switching to a mu-plugin, I tried:

```
// Callback loading the textdomain 'my-plugin', defined as such in header of main plugin file
public function my_plugin_load_muplugin_textdomain() {
      load_muplugin_textdomain(
        'my-plugin',
        'my-plugin/languages'
      );
}

// Hook of it
add_action(
        'muplugins_loaded',
        array( $this, 'my_plugin_load_muplugin_textdomain' )
      );
```

I.E.:

1. changed the function called in the callback from `load_plugin_textdomain()` to `load_muplugin_textdomain()`, and adapted parameters as above.
2. Changed action hook from `plugins_loaded` to `muplugins_loaded`
3. Changed Domain Path in main plugin file header from `/languages` to `/my-muplugin/languages`

Yet, the localization of my mu plugin is still not working. I rechecked the locales as well, and I'm using the correct ones (for example, when I change the users language in the wp admin from german to english(UK), my translation file named `my-plugin-en_GB.mo` is not applied, and everything still appears in german).

Help??

Comment: Would it not be easier to keep it as a plugin, then write an mu plugin that filters the activated plugins so it cannot be removed or deactivated? Or better yet network activate the plugin if it's a multisite? `plugins-mu` isn't really intended for full blown plugins, think of it more like single file dropins

Comment: Well I only needed to employ steps 1-3 mentioned above, by using the init action hook instead of the one I wrote above; and all that's done in like 2 mins (wish I had known that about the init hook earlier). So I'm not sure what you mean by "easier" ..? For me, what you're telling me sounds much more complicated, but may due to my lack of experience in doing what you say. Also, be aware that my plugin doesn't do anything supercomplex, only basic js, ajax, php, and SQL db operations. So I wonder about the benefits of your strategy, if you could may be a lil more precise? It sounds interesting!

Comment: Also, I just noticed that there is actually an additional tab for "file dropins" under the plugins tab in the wp admin; I feel like that's what you're talking about? The thing is that I absolutely need the corresponding js etc. functions to be constantly working, so I cannot take any risk for them to be deactivated, except by explicit FTP deletion. That's why I focused on this mu-plugin switch; just to be more precise with my explanations.

Comment: No, dropins are things like `object-cache.php` etc that live in the root of `wp-content`, you can remove the deactivate link via https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253902/hide-wordpress-plugin-deactivation-links you can also network activate it so that only super admins can deactivate. You can also keep the plugin in the plugins folder and load it via mu-plugins, then it won't matter if it's active or not. You can also override the `active_plugins` option

Comment: You can also auto-activate it via code https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-to-activate-plugins-via-code

Comment: Alright, removing the delete link would have been even faster indeed, though I feel "safer" having it as mu-plugin now... I however would like to understand the benefits of your strategy, to decide if I may switch back. When you say that ```mu-plugins``` are not intended for functional plugins; why do you say so? Are there different performances? Concretely: What's better, plugin without deletion links, or mu-plugins? Does it matter, and if so, why? Sorry for eventual inconveniences, I'd like to understand things properly. Thanks a lot for your infos!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109498/discussion-between-develjoe-and-tom-j-nowell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `init` action hook instead of the `muplugins_loaded` action hook did the job! But I wonder if that's the proper way of doing it..?